# Replacing XmlSerializer due to slow WPF application start-up

Tags: wpf, startup, xmlserializer

I have wrote a WPF application that reads a list of movies from a XML file at a network location. When I started investigating the slow start-up it turned out that XmlSerializer has a lot overhead.

I have now used sgen to build the assemblies before I publish the project but I am now looking into a better solution. I have looked at the BinaryFormatter class but the XML file is created by a PHP script running on the Linux server.

Would I be better to use an XML file reader and loop through the file myself or is there a better option? I am aiming for speed so any suggestions to replace my XmlSerializer are welcome.

Here is the code for de-serializing the the file.

```
    public List<Movie> DeSerializeXmlObject(string filename)
    {
        List<Movie> movies;
        Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Movie>));
        movies = (List<Movie>)s.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return movies;
    }
```

I couldn't figure out how to attach files so I pasted the XML file onto pastebin. http://pastebin.com/Rxsy0R3c
Thanks
Ben

Comment: Can you delay the deserialization?  If so, you might be able to do lazy loading of the assemblies via unity/prism, until you actually need it in your program.  Then your load times would be faster. http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/, http://unity.codeplex.com/

Comment: well the first window shows a list view with all the movies in. Would calling the deserialization method in the Loaded event make much difference to calling it in the Window constructor?

Comment: I would suspect the Loaded event not to make much difference. How big is the XML file and how complex are your entities you're serializing into?

Comment: The file is 85kb and the entities have 4 properties.

Comment: You've said it's on network location? Maybe it's network access that is time-consuming. How big is the delay you're facing? 85K is not much at all.

Comment: For a cold start it can be up to around 45 seconds and that's via Gigabit lan. I tried the code with a local index file but it didn't seem to make a difference which is what made me think there was something wrong with the deserializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is high possibility you are doing something wrong. Parsing even 1MB xml would take no more than 1 second. Would you kindly post your serialization and deserialization code with XML file you are trying to parse?

Edit: Sorry, I think I cant help you. Your code and file looks alright. Only option I see now is lazy load this file in background worker and then set movies back in GUI thread.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the code. I have also pasted the XML file to pastebin.

Comment: I lazy loaded the file, it seemed that the main part of the delay was bringing the file over the network.